# Why does tap water in New York remain 50 to 60°F year round?

Tags: water-resources

Throughout last few weeks in NYC, cold water temperature is 50 - 52°F. And no, it is not drawn from ground water resorvoir.

Comment: Technically it isn't everywhere in NYC.  It does differ in some buildings, and will differ based on what the pipes are exposed to.  However people work harder than most end users realize to prevent pipes from freezing.

Comment: are the supply pipes underground? If so what is the ground temperature at that depth? Used that for a fresh air supply to our house - warm in winter, cool in summer...

Answer (score 1):

At a certain depth in the ground, the soil temperature remains almost constant throughout the year at about 50-55 degrees F. This is because it is being (gently) warmed from below by heat diffusing out from the earth's core, which keeps it warm even though the soil surface above it is covered with snow.